# How to fetch the cherry-picked commit ID's on daily basis from gerrit server

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy

I have a AOSP repo, which has many git projects and developers keep on check in their code once it is reviewed in the gerrit server. So the commit ID will be mentioned as cherry-picked commit ID in the gerrit.

I want to get the list of all the developers commit ID's which are cherry-picked (reviewed and pushed into the server) on daily basis.

How could I get those list instead of getting into gerrit server manually.

Is there any possibility of doing it using Jenkins job?

Comment: Suppose that `git cherry-pick A` creates a new commit `B`. Is "the cherry-picked commit" in the question referring to `A` or `B`?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am asking for the commit ID 'B'.

Answer (score 1):

Gerrit provides an SSH command `gerrit query` to query the changeset database.

```
ssh -p 29418 ${gerrit_username}@${gerrit_host} gerrit query comment:"Cherry Picked from branch" OR message:"cherry picked from commit" --current-patch-set --format json -S 0
```

The command returns at most 501 records. The last record has a key `moreChanges`. If its value is `true`, there are extra records. Set `-S 0` to `-S 500` to skip the first 500 and run the command again. If `moreChanges` is `true`, add 500 more to skip. `-S 1000`, `-S 1500`, until `moreChanges` is `false`.

Each record is a string in the format of JSON. Parse it and you can get the necessary values. To limit the output, you need to add more conditions, like `before:xxx`, `after:xxx`, `project:xxx`, `branch:xxx`. See [Query Operators](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-search.html).

Besides, Gerrit provides an equivalent REST api.

```
GET /changes/?q=<querystring>&o=<options>
```

For example with `curl`,

```
curl --digest -s --user ${gerrit_username}:${http_password} "http://${gerrit_host}/gerrit/a/changes/?q=comment:%22Cherry Picked from branch%22+OR+message:%22cherry picked from commit%22&S=500&o=CURRENT_REVISION"
```

You can find `${http_password}` in Gerrit Settings. If none exists, press `Generate Password` on the setting page. `%22` is `"` in url. `S=500` is equivalent to `-S 500`. `o=CURRENT_REVISION` is equivalent to `--current-patch-set`.

If you intend to use `python`, `golang` or other languages to call the api, remember to use `digest access authentication`,

For more details, see [Gerrit Query](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-query.html), [REST API Notes](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/dev-rest-api.html) and [Query Change](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#list-changes).

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way.

I tried "git pull" in all the git projects in the repo in the morning using a shell script and will store the latest commit ID in an array, so that it will get all the latest commits of each project.

Then I can get the latest commits in each of the git projects.

But I accept that there is no work of Jenkins and Gerrit here.

Anyhow thanks for your response ElpieKay.